# upon monitoring the XMLHttpRequest, how to detect if a request is xhr?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I hav added listener

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function(debuggeeId, message, params) {
   console.log(params);
});
```

console gives :

```
documentURL: "someurl"
frameId: "407.1"
initiator: Object
  lineNumber: 114
  type: "parser"
  url: "someurl"
  __proto__: Object
loaderId: "407.7"
request: Object
  headers: Object
    Accept: "text/css,*/*;q=0.1"
    Cache-Control: "max-age=0"
    Referer: "someurl"
    User-Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
    __proto__: Object
  method: "GET"
  url: "someurl"
  __proto__: Object
requestId: "407.861"
timestamp: 1402725779.200758
```

Now how do i find if the request type is xhr or documents or scripts or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of my problem found on below concept:

When we add listener on `"chrome.onEvent"` (generic event) then then callback is called whenever any event is called. Each event has a particular message. The real misunderstanding : I was thinking a request have type 'xhr' or something..

But actually : "a request can never have any type xhr, documents or etc." and "a response always have a type xhr, documents or etc.".

I was consoling  only one occurrence of request parameter because the event was being called with message : `"Network.requestWillBeSent"` and i ignored to show the response parameter in other occurrences.

a response parameter will the received when the message is :  `"Network.responseReceived"` and then third parameter (here params) will have a property type which will tell if the response was xhr, or anything else

```
chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(function(debuggeeId, message, params) {
   if(message == 'Network.requestWillBeSent') { //chrome requests to server
     console.log(params.type);  //always undefined (as request never have property 'type')
   } else if((message === "Network.responseReceived") { //chrome receives response
     console.log(params.type); //shows which type of response recieved (xhr, or something else)
     if(params.type == 'XHR') {
       //DO YOUR WORK WITH XHR
     }
   } else if(message == "Network.loadingFinished") {
     //Here loading is finished. and now chrome dev tool filter the responses  as per type (responses of only those requests whose response is received, rest requests are in pending queue at current timestamp)
   }
});
```

And this is the way chrome dev tool filter the network
Chrome does not decide if response of a request will be 'xhr' or something. So it keeps the type as 'pending' untill the response is recieved.
and when response is recieved it categorises the network as xhr or documents or css or etc.
see the two pending request in image which get replaced with some 'type' after the response in recieved

[image]

Comment: Interesting. but how to explain there are no responses but with "Failed to load response data" for two requests and their network type are XHR and documents respectively in Chrome developer tools

Answer (score -1):

You can [set the XHR Breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-xhr) to 'Any XHR' in Chrome devtools under the Sources tab.